# Подсчёт повторяющихся строк в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется массив с большим количеством строк, например:

```
array1 = ['abc def','def abc','fgh jkl']
```

Как подсчитать количество строк в массиве, учитывая, что строка `'abc def'` тоже самое, что и строка `'def abc'`?

То есть, я должен получить что-то вроде этого:

```
count = ({'abc def':2, 'fgh jkl':1})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [14]: from collections import Counter

In [15]: a = ['abc def','def abc', 'abc def abc', 'fgh jkl']

In [16]: c = Counter(' '.join(sorted(s.split())) for s in a)

In [17]: c
Out[17]: Counter({'abc def': 2, 'abc abc def': 1, 'fgh jkl': 1})

In [18]: dict(c)
Out[18]: {'abc def': 2, 'abc abc def': 1, 'fgh jkl': 1}
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!